# Can't move items in qgraphicsscene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to add items to qgraphicsscene, and move them later. I am using QMainWindow and QFrames to organize content of window and I can add items, but can't move the items. In tutorials I have found authors use QDialog and QgraphicsView as the only widget. Is that what makes the difference ? QMainWindow does not pass mouse events to GraphicsView or QGraphicsScene ? Any help appreciated.

```
def _add_area(self):
  item = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
  brush = QBrush()
  brush.setStyle(Qt.Dense7Pattern)
  brush.setColor(Qt.darkBlue)
  item.setBrush(brush)
  item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
  item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
  self._scene.addItem(item)
```

Comment: Understood. If you want get good answer from someone then add your current code and add tags which shows is that you use python.

Comment: sorry, my bad, problem is not python related though. when I code logic in C++ it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I've found solution. When I removed QGraphicsView from QFrame it started working ( now QWidget is the parent of graphicsview ).